# Add nested elements to @XmlAnyElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using JAXB and I have a problem.

I have an Element with a dynamic number of properties. As a result, the structure of its equivalent XML structure will not be static. This is an example of the desired XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<element>
 <property1>value 1</property1>
 <property2>value 2</property2>
 <property3>value 3</property3>
 <propertyn>value n</propertyn>
</element>
```

To generate this, I used @XmlAnyElement like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "element")
public class Element {

    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @XmlTransient
    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Map<String, String> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<JAXBElement<String>> getElements() {

        List<JAXBElement<String>> elements = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>>();

        for (String property: properties.keySet()) {
            JAXBElement<String> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(property), String.class, properties.get(property));
            elements.add(jaxbElement);
        }       

        return elements;
    }

}
```

This works fine! However, I'm trying to add nested elements to support multi-value properties, so that the XML will be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<element>
  <property1>value 1</property1>
  <property2>value 2</property2>
  <property3>value 3</property3>
  <property4>
    <value>value 4a</value>
    <value>value 4b</value>
    <value>value 4c</value>
  </property4>
  <propertyn>value n</propertyn>
</element>
```

Please note that:

1. The number of properties is not static.
2. The number of multi-value properties is not static.
3. The number of values of each multi-value property is not static.

My question is, how can I do that in a simple way? Is @XmlElementWrapper useful in my case?

Thanks!